# Using multicharacter field separator using AWK

Tags: awk

I'm having problems with AWK's field delimiter, 
the input file appears as below

> 1  |   all |       |   synonym |
>   1  |   root    |       |   scientific name |
>   2  |   Bacteria    |   Bacteria    |   scientific name |
>   2  |   Monera  |   Monera    |   in-part |
>   2  |   Procaryotae |   Procaryotae   |   in-part |
>   2  |   Prokaryota  |   Prokaryota    |   in-part |
>   2  |   Prokaryotae |   Prokaryotae   |   in-part |
>   2  |   bacteria    |   bacteria    |   blast name  |

the field delimiter here is tab,pipe,tab `\t|\t`
so in my attempt to print just the 1st and 2nd column

```
awk -F'\t|\t' '{print $1 "\t" $2}' nodes.dmp | less
```

instead of the desired output, the output is the 1st column followed by the pipe character. I tried escaping the pipe `\t\|\t`, but the output remains the same.

> 1  |
>   1  |
>   2  |
>   2  |
>   2  |
>   2  |

Printing the 1st and 3rd column gave me the original intended output.

```
awk -F'\t|\t' '{print $1 "\t" $3}' nodes.dmp | less
```

but i'm puzzed as to why this is not working as intended.

I understand that the perl one liner below will work but what i really want is to use awk.

```
perl -aln -F"\t\|\t" -e 'print $F[0],"\t",$F[1]' nodes.dmp | less
```

Answer (score 6):

The pipe `|` character seems to be confusing `awk` into thinking that `\t|\t` implies that the field separator could be *one* of `\t` or `\t`.  Tell awk to interpret the `|` literally.

```
$ awk -F'\t[|]\t' '{print $1 "\t" $2}'
1   all
1   root
2   Bacteria
2   Monera
2   Procaryotae
2   Prokaryota
2   Prokaryotae
2   bacteria
```

Comment: so does this mean that whatever within the square brackets will be interpreted as it is and not some metachar in awk's regex. But how come it did not work when we escape the pipe? `\|` and is [] the preferred way of escaping metachar in cases similar to the above example?

Comment: @WesleyGoi Anything within `[]` denotes a character class and is interpreted as is.  Of course, you could also escape the `|` by saying `\|` and that should also work.  Saying `[|]` appears cleaner, though.

Comment: To be clear - using `\t|\t` is not confusing awk; awk understand it perfectly to mean EXACTLY what it does mean, that the FS is `\t` OR `\t`. It's the OP who was confused over how to write an ERE that means `\t` `PIPE-SYMBOL` `\t`. Also, using `\|` doesn't work because REs specified in a string are parsed twice, once when read and again when used, so you need to escape metacharacters twice, i.e. `\\|`.

Comment: thanks for clearing it up but it seems escaping twice did not work

Comment: @WesleyGoi Using `awk -F'\t\\|\t' '{print $1 "\t" $2}'` does work for me, but really, using a character class is easier on the eye anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From your posted input:

1. your lines can end in `|`, not `|\t`, and
2. you have cases (the first 2 lines) where the input contains `|\t|`, and
3. your lines start with a tab

So, an FS of tab-pipe-tab is wrong since it won't match any of the above cases since the first is just tab-pipe and the tab in the middle of the second will match the tab-pipe-tab from the preceding field but then that just leaves pipe-tab for the following field, and the first leaves you with an undesirable leading tab.

What you actually need is to set the FS to just tab-pipe and then strip off the leading tab from each field:

```
awk -F'\t|' -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/(^|[|])\t/,""); print $1, $2}' file
```

That way you can handle all fields from 1 to NF-1 exactly the same as each other.

Comment: Hi ed, when i pasted the example input in, it somehow cut off the last tab, either that it was my fault.
And regarding the occurences of the |\t| it was suppose to be an empty field ie. \t|\t\t|\t again when I inputed it the site sort of changed it. And the same for 3.

Comment: ^ changed the example above to fit the description, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` command:

```
 cut -f1,2 -d'|' file.txt
```

without `pipe` in output:

```
 cut -f1,2 -d'|' file.txt | tr -d '|'
```